# Custom component user object value

Tags: jsf-2, custom-component

I want to create a custom component in JSF2 (kind of improve outputLink), is it possible to use custom user object in the attribute?

```
<my:cLink param="#{bean.userObject}" />

private MyUserClass userObject
```

Do you know tutorial for creating custom component in JSF2.0, I found http://www.exadel.com/web/portal/jsftutorial-customcomponents but it's for JSF1.2. I see that some annotation appear to simplify the business.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already on JSF 2.0, are you sure that you want to create a [custom component](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnavg.html) rather than a [composite component](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqzr.html)? Either way, certainly you must be able to use non-standard types as attribute value. In a custom component which extends [`UIComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html) (or better, [`UIComponentBase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html)), you can use the inherited [`getAttributes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getAttributes%28%29) method to obtain it:

```
Object param = getAttributes().get("param");
```

There's only one annotation for custom components, the [`@FacesComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/FacesComponent.html). It is just a replacement of the `<component>` entry in `faces-config.xml`. For the remnant there are no big differences between JSF 1.2 and 2.0, expect of the new support for partial state saving. You could safely follow the JSF 1.2 targeted tutorials for custom components.

Comment: why don't use `Object param = getAttributes.get("param");` ? What is the difference between `getAttributes` and `getValueExpression`?