# JSF 2.0 Custom Component - how to retrieve object instead of String from Component

Tags: java, jsf-2, custom-component

I'm creating a custom component whose attribute accepts an instance of an object
like this

```
<hy:bean instance="#{myManagedBean.person}" />
```

How do I retrieve this instance in my Renderer?

I tried the following but I only get a version of the component converted to a string

```
Object instance = beanComponent.getAttributes().get( "instance" );
```

If I do below, i get a NullpointerException

```
//expecting "#{myManagedBean.person}" which i can then evaluate
String instance = beanComponent.getInstance();
```

this is the definition of getInstance() in BeanComponent

```
public String getInstance()
{
   return ( String ) getStateHelper().get( PropertyKeys.instance );
}

public void setInstance( String instance )
{
    getStateHelper().put( PropertyKeys.instance, instance );
}
```

I observed that the Setter is never called.

Any idea how I can get the Object of #{myManagedBean.person} for introspection?

Comment: I have a feeling you should try to extract the value binding instead of the value itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Object instance = beanComponent.getValueExpression("instance").
                    getValue(context.getELContext());
```

Thanks to this answer
[Custom component user object value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265272/custom-component-user-object-value)